# Parsing rss feed using xml serializer

Tags: windows-phone-8

Can anybody please tell me how can I parse this Url

http://bitcast-r.v1.sjc1.bitgravity.com/objectinfo/MIB/radio/inbradio_play.xml

such that all items in feed except the first item should be displayed in listbox.I am unable to understand how to parse omiting the first item.
This is the code I was using for parsing.But in this case I was getting all items of a feed.
But I need not get first item (i.e) torilive.How can I parse such that I should not get first item

**MainPage.xaml.cs:**

```
 public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        // is there network connection available


        if (!System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No network connection available!");
            return;
        }
        // start loading XML-data
        WebClient downloader = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri("http://bitcast-r.v1.sjc1.bitgravity.com/objectinfo/MIB/radio/inbradio_play.xml", UriKind.Absolute);
        downloader.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(ChannelDownloaded);
        downloader.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }

    void ChannelDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
        }
        else
        {
            // Deserialize if download succeeds
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Channel));
            XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
           Channel channel = (Channel)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());
            listBox.ItemsSource = channel.Collection;
        }
    }
```

**Channel.cs:**

```
    namespace Sample
    {
        [XmlRoot("rss")]
        public class Channel
    {
        [XmlArray("channel")]
        XmlArrayItem("item")]
        public ObservableCollection<Items> Collection { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

**Items.cs:**

```
namespace Sample
{
    public class Items
    {
        [XmlElement("title")]
        public string title { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("link")]
        public string link { get; set; }

         [XmlElement("image")]
         public string image { get; set; }
    }
 }
```

Hope anybody helps.Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Post the code you are running now.

Comment: Yes sir I have posted the code in above.

Answer (score 0):

Nice program :)

---

C#

```C#
void ChannelDownloaded(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Result == null || e.Error != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("There was an error downloading the XML-file!");
    }
    else
    {
        // Deserialize if download succeeds
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Channel));
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
        Channel channel = (Channel)serializer.Deserialize(document.CreateReader());


        // remove the first item
        if (channel.Collection.Count > 0)
            channel.Collection.RemoveAt(0);

        this.myListBox.ItemsSource = channel.Collection;            
   }
}
```

---

XAML

```XAML
<ListBox x:Name="myListBox">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="0,0,0,1" BorderBrush="Red">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding title}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding link}" Width="350"></TextBlock>
                <Image Source="{Binding image}" Width="50" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Image>
            </StackPanel>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

---

Code In Action:

[image]

---

You can modify the template to get your desired results.

Comment: Rearlly I was very much thankful to you.But here I had another promblem.I have to play the first item audio as default.That means I have to pass the link of first item to mediaelement.but how can I pass.for any item in listbox I was using string s=items.link.And passing s to mediaelement. MediaElement1.Source =new Uri(s, UriKind.Absolute);Mediaelement.play();But here I was not getting.How can I pass first item link to mediaelement.

Comment: @deepu Your comment is very confusing, it probably warrants another SO post.  I think I answered your original question fully.

Comment: can you please tell me how can I omit the first item in this situation  var queue = from item in document.Descendants("item")
                            select new Item
                            {
                                title=item.Element("title").Value,
link =item.Element("link").Value,
                            ThumbnailUrl=item.Element(item.GetNamespaceOfPrefix("media") + "thumbnail").Attribute("url").Value
                                ,
                                };
              itemsList.ItemsSource = queue;Thanking you